# Passing the value of pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I wanted to create a simple program to better understand how the pointers work and I came across a problem. I want to work on 3 files main.c modul.c and modul.h.

**modul.h**

```
typedef struct                                                                               
{                                                                                          
   int data;                                                                                 
}w_options;                                                                                
int show(); //prototype of function
```

**modul.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "modul.h"

int show()
{

  w_options *color;
  color = (w_options *)malloc(sizeof(w_options));
  printf("%d\n", color->data);

  if (color->data == 1)
  {
    printf("Good\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Bad\n");
  }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "modul.h"

int main()
{
   w_options *color;
   color = (w_options *)malloc(sizeof(w_options));
   color->data=1;
   printf("%d\n", color->data);
   show(); 
}
```

In **main.c** I am setting the value of `color->data` to 1 and it's working, it's printing 1. But I would like to pass this set value to **modul.c**. That's way I created simple `if` instruction to check if the value is passed. Unfortunately the value isn't passed and I don't have idea how to fix it. I need this kind of solution for my bigger program.

The Output:

```
1
0
Bad
```

Comment: You didn't pass anything to `show()`?

Comment: Are you aware that the (local) `color` variable in `show` is *different* from the `color` variable in `main`? You need to modify the signature of that function and actually *pass* that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to pass it as an argument to your function. And, as your function returns nothing, declare it as void.

**modul.h**

```
typedef struct                                                                               
{
   int data;
}w_options;
void show(w_options *color); //prototype of function
```

**modul.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "modul.h"

void show(w_options *color)
{


  if (color->data == 1)
  {
    printf("Good\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Bad\n");
  }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "modul.h"

int main()
{
  w_options *color;
  color = (w_options *)malloc(sizeof(w_options));
  color->data=1;
  printf("%d\n", color->data);
  show(color);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you aren't passing any values.

In `modul.c` you're creating one pointer named `color` that has no initialized values, you are only allocating memory.

```
color = (w_options *)malloc(sizeof(w_options));
printf("%d\n", color->data);
```

It's an accident that it happens to print `0` as the current value. This isn't guaranteed at all.

In `main.c` you're creating another different pointer, also named `color` but in a different scope, whose own `color->data` is set to `1`.

```
color = (w_options *)malloc(sizeof(w_options));
color->data=1;
printf("%d\n", color->data);
```

This correctly prints `1` as the current value because you've initialized it properly.

If you want `show` to use a pointer, pass the pointer to it as an argument and use it on the other end.

#### main.c

```
...
show(color);
...
```

#### modul.c

```
...
int show(w_options *color)
{

  // this is a parameter now, receiving the value from its caller
  //w_options *color;
  //color = (w_options *)malloc(sizeof(w_options));
  printf("%d\n", color->data);

  if (color->data == 1)
  {
    printf("Good\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Bad\n");
  }
}
...
```